# Null location when trying google maps demos

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Here is the scenario that led to getting null location:

1. Go to Setting -> Location Access .> Turn Off `WiFi & mobile network location`.
2. Open the Demo app.
3. Select `MyLocationDemoActivity`.
4. Click on `My Location` button. You will get `Location: null` in a Toast.

However, if you Turn on `WiFi & mobile network location`, the location is returned. So, here is some questions:

1. In my app, should I assume that `WiFi & mobile network location` is turned on by default (the same the demo did)?
2. If not, how to detect that and show an appropriate message?
3. And is it a good practice to store the last location in (let's say `SharedPreference`) for usage when the Network Location is turned off?

This is `MyLocationDemoActivity` for your reference:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.mapdemo;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This demo shows how GMS Location can be used to check for changes to the users location.  The
 * "My Location" button uses GMS Location to set the blue dot representing the users location. To
 * track changes to the users location on the map, we request updates from the
 * {@link LocationClient}.
 */
public class MyLocationDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

  private GoogleMap mMap;

  private LocationClient mLocationClient;
  private TextView mMessageView;

  // These settings are the same as the settings for the map. They will in fact give you updates at
  // the maximal rates currently possible.
  private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
      .setInterval(5000)         // 5 seconds
      .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
      .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);
    mMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
    mLocationClient.connect();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mLocationClient != null) {
      mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }
  }

  private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
      // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
      mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
             .getMap();
      // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
      if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
      }
    }
  }

  private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
    if (mLocationClient == null) {
      mLocationClient = new LocationClient(
          getApplicationContext(),
          this,  // ConnectionCallbacks
          this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
    }
  }

  /**
   * Button to get current Location. This demonstrates how to get the current Location as required,
   * without needing to register a LocationListener.
   */
  public void showMyLocation(View view) {
    if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
      String msg = "Location = " + mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Implementation of {@link LocationListener}.
   */
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mMessageView.setText("Location = " + location);
  }

  /**
   * Callback called when connected to GCore. Implementation of {@link ConnectionCallbacks}.
   */
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        REQUEST,
        this);  // LocationListener
  }

  /**
   * Callback called when disconnected from GCore. Implementation of {@link ConnectionCallbacks}.
   */
  @Override
  public void onDisconnected() {
    // Do nothing
  }

  /**
   * Implementation of {@link OnConnectionFailedListener}.
   */
  @Override
  public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Do nothing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to detect GPS and Network availability for location

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

boolean GPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean NetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

No, don't store the last location. Use `getLastKnownLocation` instead.

Comment: I think we should use [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) instead of [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) as of v2, shouldn't we?

Comment: Not necessarily, besides: `LocationClient` relies on `Google Play Services` which may not be available in every device.

Comment: I am relying on it. My app uses Google maps.

Comment: So, you're gonna have to use both since there's no way to find out whether location services are enabled using only `LocationClient`, otherwise `LocationManager` would be deprecated by now.

Comment: Exception-al is not necessarily right, as for `LocationClient`, checking whether the location services are enabled is automatic. This can be done by simply setting the `LocationRequest`'s priority to LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, and the API itself will take care to check which location service to use. LocationClient is more about trusting Google, and LocationManager is more about being independent and making your checks manually.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was facing the same issue.
I did something like this:

```
private boolean posChecked = false;

//import OnMyLocationChangeListener
//from import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener; 

@Override
public void OnMyLocationChanged(Location location){

    if(!checked){
        //now your getMyLocation() wont be null
    }

}
```

You cannot be sure, that you'll get a non-null object from `getMyLocation()` on the `OnCreate()` because the Google `MapFragment` load is asynchronous.

Hope this helps ;)